# Connection Timeout With File_get_contents()

Tags: php, file, curl

I am working on a script that fetches csv files from a web server. I am using file_get_contents presently. Sometimes i get the message

```
Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

I assume it can be due to website being down. Or can there be a situation where the website is fine but still this warning shows up. Also what advantage does CURL provide over this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because the remote url is having 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing remote files, you should use cURL.  You can set cURL to timeout quietly if the remote server takes too long.